# How to deploy a flow that uses SCV_Outbound_Call action?

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment

Using this command:
sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts

to deploy a flow to a scratch org fails with this error:

SCV_Outbound_Call (Action) - The action type "SCV Outbound Call" can't be used in flows with the process type "Autolaunched Flow".

Seems to indicate you cannot have that SCV_Outbound_Call action in an Autolaunched Flow, however the Salesforce docs show the steps on how to create an Autolaunched Flow with that same action, here:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.voice_hvoc_autolaunched_flow.htm&type=5

I was successful in creating the flow in my scratch org with that action and then pulling it down locally.
I then made a one digit change in the phone number field in the metadata xml file and tried to push/deploy the change to the scratch org and got the error above:

sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts

SCV_Outbound_Call (Action) - The action type "SCV Outbound Call" can't be used in flows with the process type "Autolaunched Flow".

I also tried moving the flow to a directory adjacent to the force-app folder and deploying via the metadata API command and got an error as well:

sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d unpackaged-metadata/flows

Deploy has been queued.

Then if I checked the deployment results with
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report -i 0Af5300000XlWO3CAN -u scoder@scr.com

It responded with

Status: Failed
Deployed: 0/0 Errors: 0
Tests Complete: 0/0 Errors: 0
Error (1): The metadata deploy operation failed.

The legacy sfdx command also fails:

sfdx force:source:push -f -u scr

SCV_Outbound_Call (Action) - The action type "SCV Outbound Call" can't be used in flows with the process type "Autolaunched Flow".

Can this only be deployed with say a changeset?